# Python parallel processing fills memory fast

Tags: python, parallel-processing, brute-force

I'm bruteforcing a 8-digit pin on a ELF executable (it's for a CTF) and I'm using asynchronous parallel processing. The code is very fast but it fills the memory even faster.
It takes about 10% of the total iterations to fill 8gbs of ram, and I have no idea what's causing it. Any help?

```
from pwn import *
import multiprocessing as mp
from tqdm import tqdm

def check_pin(pin):
    program = process('elf_exe')
    program.recvn(36)

    program.sendline(str(pin))

    program.recvline()
    program.recvline()
    res = program.recvline()
    
    program.close()

    if 'Access denied.' in str(res):
        return null, null
    else:
        return res, pin

def process_result(res, pin):
    if(res != null):
        print(pin)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(f'Starting bruteforce on {mp.cpu_count()} cores :)\n')
    pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())  

    min = 10000000
    max = 99999999
    for pin in tqdm(range(min, max)):
        pool.apply_async(check_pin, args=(pin), callback=process_result)

    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Answer (score 3):

Multiprocessing pools create several processes. Calls to `apply_async` create a task that is added to a shared data structure (eg. queue). The data structure is read by processes thanks to inter-process communication (IPC). The thing is `apply_async` return a synchronization object that you do not use and so **there is not synchronizations**. Items appended in the data structure take some memory space (at least 32*3=96 bytes due to 3 CPython objects being allocated) and the data structure grow in memory to hold the 89_999_999 items hence at least 8 GiB of RAM. The process are not fast enough to execute the work. What `tqdm` print is totally is completely misleading: it just print the processing of the number of task submitted, not the one executed that is only a tiny fraction. Almost all the work is done when `tqdm` print 100% and the submission loop is done. I actually doubt the "code is very fast" since it appears to run 90 millions process while running a process is known to be an expensive operation.

To speed up this code and avoid a big memory usage, you need to **aggregate the work in bigger tasks**. You can for example and a range of `pin` variable to be computed and add a loop in `check_pin`. A reasonable range size is for example 1000. Additionally, you need to accumulate the `AsyncResult` objects returned by `apply_async` in a list and perform **periodic synchronizations** when the list becomes too big so that processes does not have too much work and so the shared data structure can remain small. Here is a simple untested example:

```py
lst = []
for rng in allRanges:
    lst.append(pool.apply_async(check_pin, args=(rng), callback=process_result))
    if len(lst) > 100:
        # Naive synchronization
        for i in lst:
            i.wait()
        lst = []
```